# Banach algebra.

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

Iam new in this field. I am reading a paper and have encoutered the following Lemma.

Let $u\in F_{1}.$ Then $Sp(u)=\{0, tr(u)\},$ where $F_{1}$ is the set of one-dimensional elements and tr(u) is the trace of $u.$ Can someone kindly help me with some hints on how I can use the Spectral mapping theorem for the proof to this Lemma. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: What is the Banach algebra where $F_1$ is a subset? Also I don't understand what you mean by one-dimensional elements. If this is an algebra of operators, I would assume that you have some trace-class operators, or do you mean something else by trace?

Comment: Thanks Minimalrho. It is a Semi-prime Banach algebra.